Adding/updating comments for multiple columns in a delta table
I'm trying to update the comments for over 200 columns for several tables. I have a config dictionary where these column names and comments are defined. Using this dictionary I want to update the comments for the respective fields.
Although looping through each column and running alter command looks straight forward, I want to see concurrent updates for better performance as the number of columns are pretty high.
Below is the attempt 1 (sequential execution : time taking) -
columns_comments = {
    "col1": "comment1",
    "col2": "comment2",
    ....
    "col236": "comment236",
}

for col, comment in columns_comments.items():
    spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN {col} SET COMMENT '{comment}'")

Attempt 2 -
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ALTER COLUMN col1 SET COMMENT 'comment1',
  ALTER COLUMN col2 SET COMMENT 'comment2',
  ....
  ALTER COLUMN col236 SET COMMENT 'comment236';

Error - org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'COMMENT'.(line 2, pos 45)

-- It appears that the comma after alter column is not accepted.

I've tried it on Databricks Runtime Versions - 13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12) and 14.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12).
Any suggestions on better approach. Thanks!
